# Loading several files

Tags: files, uploading

I am part of application development team.
We are writing an application which takes several geographic files (shape files) and finds where a coordinate intersects with each of the files

I would like to allow the user to enter an arbitrary amount of geographic files. e.g. he could find the intersection with 1 to 10 shape files.

**I want to know what is the best practice of choosing several files**. Currently I give the user the option to choose a directory where all the shape files are located however it doesn't feel right.

Comment: Related: http://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/2847/multiple-file-selection-for-web-file-upload

Comment: Why doesn't it feel right to you? Is the user not able to navigate away from the directory?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would suggest providing a solution where the user selects the files she wants to upload. This is the pattern that Dropbox use and I think it brings a few advantages. Firstly the the user is not obligated to upload the entire content of a folder, which is good since it's not certain that this is what the user wants to do. Secondly it will limit uploading of unintended files, since the user will have better oversight and control over which files are being uploaded through a direct manipulation interface (the user points and clicks on the specific files that are of interest).

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

So I would greatly encourage you to follow suit in this case.

Comment: I wouldn't count on users knowing how to command-click to select multiple files, but +1 for drag & drop.